# Elegant way to pass objects to Laravel's create method

Tags: laravel-5

Is there a more elegant way to do the following in Lavarel 5?

```php
MyModel::create([
    'my_other_model_id' => $my_other_model->id,
    'my_other_other_model_id' => $my_other_other_model->id,
]);
```

I'd like to pass `$my_other_model` and `$my_other_other_model` in directly without all that tedious mucking about with `id`s.

Answer (score 1):

The following more elegant code is possible to do with [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators).

```php
MyModel::create([
    'my_other_model' => $my_other_model,
    'my_other_other_model' => $my_other_other_model,
]);
```

---

#### App/MyModel.php

```php
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model {
  protected function setMyOtherModelAttribute(MyOtherModel $my_other_model) {
    $this->attributes['my_other_model_id'] = $my_other_model->getKey();
  }

  protected function setMyOtherOtherModelAttribute(MyOtherOtherModel $my_other_other_model) {
    $this->attributes['my_other_other_model_id'] = $my_other_other_model->getKey();
  }
}
```

Mutator methods are called `set` + «PascalCase(attribute_name)» + `Attribute`. The above code also allows doing:

```php
$my_model = new MyModel;
$my_model->my_other_model = $my_other_model;
$my_model->my_other_other_model = $my_other_other_model;
```

again without referring to any `id`s.